# How to get query execution time and query result at the same time?

Tags: mysql, query

Is there any SQL query syntax that returns query execution time and query result at the same time?

Comment: From what context? A normal select returns this information:
    `mysql> SELECT 1;
    +---+
    | 1 |
    +---+
    | 1 |
    +---+
    1 row in set (0.04 sec)`

Comment: There really isn't a redeeming quality to this question. It's not being updated/followed up on, and it's not well formed. I'm closing (it may be reopened if edited to be of quality. If so, flag and we'll consider it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @DTest, how are your running your query? If you log directly into a MySQL terminal style and hand-run queries,  it will give you a time result. Also, if you use Oracles MySQL database tool (I believe it is called "[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html)"), you can connect to your database server directly and the GUI will also give you time results for the query if you hand-run it.

Comment: I want to run it through my application and display execution time on application Windows.

Comment: @RPK since this is a question on a specific application, or programming language, you might re-ask it on stackoverflow with more details of what language you are using.